# regex matching adding chars when non-existing

Tags: regex

I am currently running in a little pitty. I am trying to simplify 2 regex rules to a single rule, but it looks like there is no way to do that. I am currently learning so, maybe there is something I missed, maybe someone can help me out.

The 2 regex are looking like that:

```
s@.*/(\d\.\d\.\d)/@Version: $1/@g
s@.*/(\d\.\d)/@Version: $1.0/@g
```

I am trying it with

```
s@.*/(\d\.\d)(\.\d)?(?(2)|\.0)/@Version $1$2$3/@g
```

but it is not working. Did I understood the conditionals wrong?
Some of the version numbers got only 2 digits and those I want suffixed by ".0".

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You have to match `.0` in the conditional for it to capture something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little problem in your regular expression:

```
s@.*/(\d\.\d)(\.\d)?(?(2)|\.0)/@Version $1$2$3/@g
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The portion I underlined is interpreted like this by Perl: If I captured something in group number 2 then do nothing, else try to match a dot `.` followed by a `0`.

It is not what you expect, in other words it doesn't capture `.0` in a group of its own.

In Perl there is a working solution for this by utilizing the `e` regular expression modifier which allows you to perform Perl code in the replacement part of the regular expression, hence exactly what we need.

```
s/(\d\.\d)(\.\d)?/'@Version ' . $1 . ($2?$2:'.0')/ge;
```

This essentially says that if you were able to match group 2 `$2?` then put `$2` in the replacement string, else put `.0` like this `:'.0'`.

Perl evaluates the replacement string as Perl code so the `.` is the concatenation operator.

[Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/kKBu9Uxp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't found /e yet, seems to be missing on http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html additionally it looks like the software can not handle /e, from the source: 
          switch(optstring[i])
      {
         case 'e': break; /* ToDo ;-) */

Comment: @Sebastian I have just modified my answer, check edit. I have also included an online demo.

Comment: @Sebastian Check this [link](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html) and a little bit down to see the `e` modifier.

Comment: Thanks sniffer, your answer is - based on perlregex - correct. The Question is solved for me, since it looks like the software I am using didnt fully implement PCRE as quoted in my comment before, /e is on their ToDo list.